# jasperreports_extension.properties overwritten by maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports

In order to have an executable jar I include the maven dependencies. Everything works fine but the `jasperreports_extension.properties`. Jasper already has a default one that replaces mine.

I'd like to know how to combine both files (the default and custom one) into the jar file. Actually I have manually combined both settings and now I want to find the way to replace the file that assembly plugin copies with the merged one I already have.

This is my current maven assembly plugin settings:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-assembly-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>
                            com.test.sample.MainClass
                        </mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

These are my custom settings to add some fonts to the reports:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory 
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.ireportfamily1453367638844=fonts/fontsfamily1453367638844.xml
```

And the dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT:**

Considering the [dependencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.2.0):

- `jasperreports_extension.properties` is inside (root level) the
  `jasperreports-6.2.0.jar`
- `jasperreports_extension.properties` is inside (root level) the
  `jasperreports-fonts-6.0.0.jar` (this is only a Test Dependencies)

After I replaced the assembly plugin by shade one, the initial issue I reported is fixed, however I got this new one:

```
    Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: no manifiest section for signature file entry org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator$EnvelopedGenerator.class
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.verifySection(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I solved this signature problem following this: ["Invalid signature file" when attempting to run a .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar)

Comment: Could you post the path to the file? And your POM also? And what do you mean by "combine both files"? What is the end result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Oh and also, could you post where that overriding `jasperreports_extension.properties` is coming from? Could you post your dependencies section?

Comment: Since it would be very interesting to see how Tunaki (one of the master's of maven on SO) would solve your problem, I have edit your question to answer some of his questions.

Comment: @Tunaki, I have edit OP question, hope that provided information is enough..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming from your question that you have a file called `jasperreports_extension.properties` as a resource of your project, located inside `src/main/resources`. Because you have a dependency on `jasperreports` that also happens to have a resource called `jasperreports_extension.properties` at the root of the classpath, one is overwriting the other when you are making the `jar-with-dependencies`.

To tackle this problem, you should drop the `maven-assembly-plugin` and use [`maven-shade-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) instead. This plugin provides out of the box a [transformer that is able to merge two properties file together](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#AppendingTransformer): by merging, I mean that one of the file is appended to the end of the other one:

> Some jars contain additional resources (such as properties files) that have the same file name. To avoid overwriting, you can opt to merge them by appending their content into one file.

In this case, a sample configuration would be:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
            <resource>jasperreports_extension.properties</resource>
          </transformer>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <mainClass>com.test.sample.MainClass</mainClass>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will produce a final fat JAR where the content of `jasperreports_extension.properties` will be the content of your file and the file coming from the dependency.

Also, it will also have a correct `MANIFEST` since we specified to the plugin which class was the main class.

---

As a side note, when you are making fat JAR, the `maven-assembly-plugin` only provides basic support. [From their homepage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/):

> If your project wants to package your artifact in an uber-jar, the assembly plugin provides only basic support. For more control, use the Maven Shade Plugin.

Comment: I have to add <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
inside the configurations tag as well,then its worked for me. Many thanks!