# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Function MONTH not found

Tags: java, groovy, jasper-reports

I'm working in a desktop application for generating reports with Java Swing and Jasper Reports. Some days ago I ran into a problem because of a Groovy function that my code was not able to find. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19459016/5310721) and the problem was solved (note I left a comment) but when I packaged my application and tried to run it from the console I got the same issue. This is the stacktrace:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Function MONTH not found.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.GroovyEvaluator.functionCall(GroovyEvaluator.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
    at subReporteSummary_1502405767221_591326.methodMissing(calculator_subReporteSummary_1502405767221_591326:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:939)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at subReporteSummary_1502405767221_591326.evaluateEstimated(calculator_subReporteSummary_1502405767221_591326:336)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluateEstimated(JREvaluator.java:342)
    ... 14 more
```

But when I inspect the jar I'm able to find the `MONTH` function, which is in the `net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.DateTimeFunctions` class

```
@Function("MONTH")
@FunctionParameters({
    @FunctionParameter("dateObject")})
public static Integer MONTH(Object dateObject){
    return getCalendarFieldFromDate(dateObject,Calendar.MONTH)+1;
}
```

from the `jasperreports-functions` package which is in my classpath and is added to the package, as you may note by my maven configuration

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <repositories>
        <!-- Jasper Reports repository to get japerreports-functions -->
        <repository>
            <id>jr-ce-releases</id>
            <url>http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/jr-ce-releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
            <!-- Exclusions to avoid some JasperReports certificates problems -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Groovy functions for Jasper Reports-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Driver needed to connect to the DB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- This is to include all my dependencies in my package (it works fine) -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>ar.edu.unt.gui.MainFrame</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <!-- I don't want to package the reports' source file -->
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.jrxml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

The `MONTH` function is called from a subreport. I found [this post](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/823601/netsfjasperreportsenginejrruntimeexception-increment-class-not-found-error) in the Jaspersoft Community but my report doesn't have such `<returnValue>` tag. This is the fragment from the main report where the subreport is declared:

```
<summary>
    <band height="239" splitType="Stretch">
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="469" height="200" uuid="2da4b923-ee34-4a6d-9a04-8d050a2feb0f"/>
            <subreportParameter name="NRO_PAGINAS_PADRE">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subReporteSummary.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <textField evaluationTime="Auto">
            <reportElement x="175" y="219" width="126" height="20" uuid="28a4ff7e-d6dd-47f5-a655-5e0ea7bec50b"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["- Página " + $V{NRO_PAGINA_ACTUAL} + " de " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + " -"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</summary>
```

And this is the `subReporteSummary.jrxml` (summarySubreport in spanish) fragment where the MONTH function is called:

```
<variable name="NOMBRE_MES" class="java.lang.String" resetType="None">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 1? "Enero" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 2? "Febrero" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 3? "Marzo" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 4? "Abril" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 5? "Mayo" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 6? "Junio" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 7? "Julio" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 8? "Agosto" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 9? "Septiembre" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 10? "Octubre" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 11? "Noviembre" : "Diciembre"]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 1? "Enero" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 2? "Febrero" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 3? "Marzo" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 4? "Abril" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 5? "Mayo" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 6? "Junio" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 7? "Julio" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 8? "Agosto" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 9? "Septiembre" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 10? "Octubre" :
    MONTH($F{fechacancelacion}) == 11? "Noviembre" : "Diciembre"]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

briefly: `fechacancelacion` is a `java.util.Date` variable and the expression is for get the month's names in upper case (is a requirement), which I can't get with a `DATEFORMAT` function because it gives me the names only in lowercase.

But getting back to the issue and to summarize, I have the `MONTH` function available in my JAR, the report compiles and shows correctly when I run my application from the IDE (Netbeans) but I'm getting an error running from the console with `java -jar myapp-1.0.jar` from the `target` folder.

If you need any other evidence, comment it out. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Most jasper function are in form 'Month' not 'MONTH', check doc

Comment: @JacekCz, I updated the post, is `MONTH` (in uppercase) and not `Month` as you can see. I've already checked it but forgot to post the snippet. Check it out please. Thanks for your time

Comment: You have jasperreports 6.4.0 but jasperreports-functions 5.2.0.  Try using jasperreports-functions 6.4.0.

Comment: jasperreports-functions 5.2.0 is the latest version available in the repositories. If you know about another repository with that version please let me know.  Best regards

Comment: @dada67, today I checked again the repository https://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/jr-ce-releases and there is the `jasperreports-functions-6.4.0.jar` since november 2016. Maybe I missed the last time I checked. However I updated my project and ran `mvn package` but the result is the same. Maybe I'll be forced to move from groovy to java in my report... pitty

Comment: If you're using the maven shade plugin to package your jar, you'll have to merge jasperreports_extension.properties from all the jars as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023908/jasperreports-extension-properties-overwritten-by-maven-assembly-plugin

Comment: @dada67 I've been in a rush with another jobs but finally I was able to try the solution in the link you posted. Please post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct (I've already voted up your comment). Thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the maven shade plugin to package your jar, you'll have to merge jasperreports_extension.properties from all the jars as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023908/jasperreports-extension-properties-overwritten-by-maven-assembly-plugin) in order for JasperReports extensions (such as functions) to be registered properly.